# Verilog implementation of trapezoidal integration method

Tags: numerical-methods, verilog, fpga

Any and all comments are welcome in this review.

### Problem

I've been doing a lot with numerical integration methods recently and have mostly been programming in Python. But...speedups! And FPGAs are cool! Thusly, I'm attempting to implement the trapezoidal integration method in Verilog. (I have never programmed in Verilog before and know almost nothing about it, hence this code review on a very short program that is probably also very crappy.)

The trapezoidal method is at its heart very simple. Take two points on your function and call them y<sub>1</sub> and y<sub>2</sub>. Then define a trapezoid with the two "bases" defined by the height from the x-axis to y<sub>1</sub> and y<sub>2</sub> and a height of the interval between the two corresponding x coordinates (i.e., x<sub>2</sub> - x<sub>1</sub>; we'll call this value x for simplicity). Then plug this into the formula for the area of a trapezoid and you get $$A = \frac{x(y_1+y_2)}{2}$$ sum this for a bunch of points with a very small value of x and you've got the integral.

The other little quirk in what I'm doing is that I'm doing it cumulatively, i.e., I'm taking in a signal (which I call `SIGNAL` in my code) and find A at that point and send it to the output (`OUT`). Then on the board I'll wire `OUT` to `SUM` and effectively add the past `OUT` to my new `OUT` to get the total area up to that point.

### Code Description

I take in several inputs - a clock signal `CLK`, the function-signal `SIGNAL` (i.e., what I'm integrating) the distance between clock ticks `x`, and the past `SUM` (again, what `OUT` is mapped to). I have one output, `OUT`, which is the solution up to that point.

I begin by defining three 64 bit registers. The first two are for the two values y<sub>1</sub> and y<sub>2</sub>, and the third is for the `SUM` (I handle it oddly). Then I start an `always` loop - whenever `CLK` is high, I set `yregtwo` equal to whatever is in `yregone` and `yregone` equal to the `SIGNAL` (effectively shifting the y values) and then check if `yregtwo` actually has something in it - i.e., that it's not step one. If this is true, then I perform the actual calculation detailed in the formula I gave above and add `SUM` to it (not `sum`). Finally, I set `sum` equal to that calculation and set `OUT` equal to `sum`.

### Full Code

```
module trapverilog(
    input CLK,
     input signed [7:0] SIGNAL,
     input signed [7:0] x,
     input signed [7:0] SUM, // OUT pins are mapped to SUM pins on board
    output reg OUTP,
     output reg OUT1,
     output reg OUT2,
     output reg OUT3,
     output reg OUT4,
     output reg OUT5,
     output reg OUT6,
     output reg OUT7
    );

reg[7:0] yregone;
reg[7:0] yregtwo;
reg[7:0] innerSumOutput;
reg[7:0] innerSum;

function [7:0] multiply;
    input [7:0] a;
    input [7:0] b;
    reg [15:0] a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8;
    begin
        a1 = (b[0]==1'b1) ? {8'b00000000, a} : 16'b0000000000000000;
        a2 = (b[1]==1'b1) ? {7'b0000000, a, 1'b0} : 16'b0000000000000000;
        a3 = (b[2]==1'b1) ? {6'b000000, a, 2'b00} : 16'b0000000000000000;
        a4 = (b[3]==1'b1) ? {5'b00000, a, 3'b000} : 16'b0000000000000000;
        a5 = (b[4]==1'b1) ? {4'b0000, a, 4'b0000} : 16'b0000000000000000;
        a6 = (b[5]==1'b1) ? {3'b000, a, 5'b00000} : 16'b0000000000000000;
        a7 = (b[6]==1'b1) ? {2'b00, a, 6'b000000} : 16'b0000000000000000;
        a8 = (b[7]==1'b1) ? {1'b0, a, 7'b0000000} : 16'b0000000000000000;
        multiply = a1 + a2 + a3 + a4 + a5 + a6 + a7 + a8;
    end
endfunction

always @(posedge CLK)
begin
    yregtwo <= yregone;
    yregone <= SIGNAL;

    if (yregone != 0)
    begin
        innerSum <= multiply((yregone + yregtwo), x); //treats x as plain h, change if treated as h/2 // multiply defined by function shift-adds
        innerSumOutput <= (innerSum <<< 1) + SUM; // <<< is signed one bit shift which = /2
        if (innerSumOutput[0] == 1)
        begin
            OUTP <= 1;
        end

        OUT1 <= innerSumOutput[1];
        OUT2 <= innerSumOutput[2];
        OUT3 <= innerSumOutput[3];
        OUT4 <= innerSumOutput[4];
        OUT5 <= innerSumOutput[5];
        OUT6 <= innerSumOutput[6];
        OUT7 <= innerSumOutput[7];
    end
end

endmodule
```

### User Config File

```
NET "CLK" LOC = P126;
NET "SIGNAL[0]" LOC = P35 | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | DRIVE = 8 | SLEW = FAST;
NET "SIGNAL[1]" LOC = P34 | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | DRIVE = 8 | SLEW = FAST;
NET "SIGNAL[2]" LOC = P33 | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | DRIVE = 8 | SLEW = FAST;
NET "SIGNAL[3]" LOC = P32 | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | DRIVE = 8 | SLEW = FAST;
NET "SIGNAL[4]" LOC = P30 | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | DRIVE = 8 | SLEW = FAST;
NET "SIGNAL[5]" LOC = P29 | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | DRIVE = 8 | SLEW = FAST;
NET "SIGNAL[6]" LOC = P27 | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | DRIVE = 8 | SLEW = FAST;
NET "SIGNAL[7]" LOC = P26 | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | DRIVE = 8 | SLEW = FAST;
NET "x[0]" LOC = P24 | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | DRIVE = 8 | SLEW = FAST;
NET "x[1]" LOC = P23 | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | DRIVE = 8 | SLEW = FAST;
NET "x[2]" LOC = P22 | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | DRIVE = 8 | SLEW = FAST;
NET "x[3]" LOC = P21 | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | DRIVE = 8 | SLEW = FAST;
NET "x[4]" LOC = P17 | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | DRIVE = 8 | SLEW = FAST;
NET "x[5]" LOC = P16 | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | DRIVE = 8 | SLEW = FAST;
NET "x[6]" LOC = P15 | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | DRIVE = 8 | SLEW = FAST;
NET "x[7]" LOC = P14 | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | DRIVE = 8 | SLEW = FAST;
NET "SUM[0]" LOC = P12 | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | DRIVE = 8 | SLEW = FAST;
NET "SUM[1]" LOC = P11 | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | DRIVE = 8 | SLEW = FAST;
NET "SUM[2]" LOC = P10 | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | DRIVE = 8 | SLEW = FAST;
NET "SUM[3]" LOC = P9 | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | DRIVE = 8 | SLEW = FAST;
NET "SUM[4]" LOC = P8 | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | DRIVE = 8 | SLEW = FAST;
NET "SUM[5]" LOC = P7 | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | DRIVE = 8 | SLEW = FAST;
NET "SUM[6]" LOC = P6 | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | DRIVE = 8 | SLEW = FAST;
NET "SUM[7]" LOC = P5 | IOSTANDARD = LVCMOS33 | DRIVE = 8 | SLEW = FAST;
```

I'm using the Mimas Spartan 6 board.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are the inputs `signed`, are you working with negative dimensions?

Most FPGAs have dedicated logic for multiplication so you usually can simply write `x*y` without having any issues. For better or worse, manually writing it out like you did could impact optimization. Be aware your `multiply` truncates most of the MSB bits. An 8-bit times 8-bit input would return a 16-bit value.

`<<< 1` is shift left and is effectively the same as multiplying by two.

Not sure why each output bit has its own port when you clearly could use a vector like the inputs.

You should add a reset and enable inputs.

Assuming your FPGA can handle \$ \frac{x(y1+y2)}{2} \$ in one clock. You could simply write:

```
module trapezoidal_integration(
    input clk, rst_n, en,
    input  [7:0] x_in, y1_in, y2_in,
    output reg [15:0] area_out,
    output reg [15:0] cum_out, // cumulative (increase width ???)
    output reg err_overflow);

  wire [15:0] area = (x_in * (y1_in+y2_in)) / 4'h2;

  always @(posedge clk) begin
    if (!rst_n) begin
      area_out <= 16'h0000;
      cum_out <= 16'h0000;
      err_overflow <= 1'b0;
    end
    else if (en) begin
      area_out <= area;
      {err_overflow,cum_out} <= cum_out + area;
    end
  end
endmodule
```

If you need to limit your pins or need to space out the operations, you could do something like below (untested example):

```
module trapezoidal_integration(
  input clk, rst_n, en,
  input [7:0] s_in,
  output reg [15:0] cum_out, // cumulative (increase width ???)
  output reg err_overflow) );

  reg [1:0] state;
  reg [16:0] tmp;

  always @(posedge clk) begin
    if (!rst_n) begin
      state <= 3'b001;
      tmp <= 17'h0_0000;
      cum_out <= 16'h0000;
      err_overflow <= 1'b0;
    end
    else begin
      case(state)
        2'b00 : begin
          tmp[7:0] <= s_in; // y1
          if (en) state <= 2'b01;
        end
        2'b01 : begin
          tmp[8:0] <= tmp[7:0] + s_in; // y1+y2
          state <= 2'b11; // gray code
        end
        2'b11 : begin
          tmp <= s_in * tmp[8:0]; // x*(y1+y2)
          state <= 2'b10; // gray code
        end
        2'b10 : begin
          {err_overflow,cum_out} <= cum_out + tmp[16:1]; // tmp[16:1] === tmp/2
          state <= 2'b00;
        end
      endcase
    end
  end
endmodule
```